# convert a txt file into array with php

Tags: php, regex, parsing

how would you take the following text from file and turn into an array? below is the code i use to read the file but right now it only puts everything into one array

```
<?php
$fileString = file_get_contents("test.txt");
  //print_r($fileString);

  //$words = preg_split("/^0\s*$/m", $fileString);
  //print_r($words);
  $rows = explode("\r", $fileString);
  print_r($rows);
 ?>

test.txt below

0
CIRCLE
8
V_DrillSF_16
39
16
10
765.1
20
57.0
30
0
40
4.0
0
CIRCLE
8
V_DrillSFS
39
16
10
765.1
20
57.0
30
0
40
3.5
0
CIRCLE
8
V_DrillSF_16
39
16
10
765.1
20
89.0
30
0
40
4.0
0
CIRCLE
8
V_DrillSF_16
39
16
10
765.1
20
249.0
30
0
40
4.0
```

i would like to break up or identify each "CIRCLE" grouping as its own array so that i can then add it to a database each "CIRCLE" grouping starts with a 0 and has the same number of rows each time.

```
[0] => Array
(
[0]=>0
[1]=>CIRCLE
[2]=>8
[3]=>V_DrillS_16
[4]=>39
[5]=>16
[6]=>10
[7]=>765.1
[8]=>20
[9]=>57.0
[10]=>30
[11]=>0
[12]=>40
[13]=>4.0
)
```

Comment: It's not clear what the end format of your expected array should be. `$rows` is currently an array, as seen by `print_r($rows);`. It sounds like the next step would be iterating over `$rows` using [a foreach loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) or [a for loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) and checking the value of the item. Then possibly adding that item to a different array (to be returned at the end) depending on if it's `CIRCLE` or not? Are you suggesting that `0\rCIRCLE\r8` is the start of a section?

Comment: FYI you can use the built-in function `file()` to read a file into an array. Then the question just becomes about how to group the elements of the array.

Comment: _“each "CIRCLE" grouping starts with a 0 and has the same number of rows each time”_ - so after using `file` as per @Barmar’s suggestion, this should not need much more than `array_chunk` then. No need to start messing around with regular expressions at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the file contents at the locations where `0\nCIRCLE` appears, and then explode each chunk with a line break (sequence) (you can again use a regex, or just `explode`).

Here is an example with `CRLF` line breaks:

```php
$fileString = "0\r\nCIRCLE\r\n8\r\nV_DrillSF_16\r\n39\r\n16\r\n10\r\n765.1\r\n20\r\n57.0\r\n30\r\n0\r\n40\r\n4.0\r\n0\r\nCIRCLE\r\n8\r\nV_DrillSFS\r\n39\r\n16\r\n10\r\n765.1\r\n20\r\n57.0\r\n30\r\n0\r\n40\r\n3.5\r\n0\r\nCIRCLE\r\n8\r\nV_DrillSF_16\r\n39\r\n16\r\n10\r\n765.1\r\n20\r\n89.0\r\n30\r\n0\r\n40\r\n4.0\r\n0\r\nCIRCLE\r\n8\r\nV_DrillSF_16\r\n39\r\n16\r\n10\r\n765.1\r\n20\r\n249.0\r\n30\r\n0\r\n40\r\n4.0";
$res = preg_split('~(*ANYCRLF)\R(?=0\RCIRCLE$)~m', $fileString);
print_r(array_map(function($x) { return explode("\r\n", $x); }, $res));
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/3GWid).

**Regex details**:

- `(*ANYCRLF)` - `\R` now matches CRLF, LF or CR line endings
- `\R` - one or more line break sequences
- `(?=^0\RCIRCLE$)` - a positive lookahead that matches

  - `^` - start of a line (due to `m`, `^` matches start of lines)
  - `0` - a `0`
  - `\R` - a single line break sequence
  - `CIRCLE` - `CIRCLE` string
  - `$` - end of a line.

Comment: i was able to get this to work if i used it exactly as you have. but when i replaced your filestring with $fileString = file_get_contents("test.txt"); I am unable to get it to work. each line in text.txt is CR LF

Comment: @heykarch Just use `explode("\r\n", $x);` or `preg_split('~\R+~u', $x)` instead.

Comment: thanks but i tried both with the above test.txt (same data as listed above in op) and both of your suggestions put everything into a single array

Comment: @heykarch See an update. You most probably need the PCRE verb `(*ANYCRLF)` to make `\R` work properly.

Comment: that worked... what does (*ANYCRLF) actually do to make this work?

Comment: @heykarch As I explained, `(*ANYCRLF)` makes the `\R` matches CRLF, LF or CR line endings, and the `.` no longer matches CR and goes on skipping LF.

Comment: thanks again I am curious is there also a way to single out a part of test.txt from above. If i only wanted to put  "CIRCLE" segment with V_DrillSFS into an array

Comment: @heykarch Sorry, I am busy right now. You might want to check `array_filter` option.